# m2eclipse's "Resolve workspace artifacts" non-functional?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Having projects A and B in Eclipse, where A has a dependency on B, everything works fine if I try to "Run As/Java Apparication" A from Eclipse. However, when I try to "Run As/Maven Build...", it complains:

```
The POM for groupname:projectb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

and then later it attempts to download my local dependency from Nexus and that of course fails.

"Resolve workspace artifacts" is enabled in the Maven run configuration. "Workspace resolution" is enabled for all projects. I have already tried:

- disabling/enabling everything
- Project/Clean everything
- Maven/Update Project everything
- Installed an external Maven (3.2.1) and repeated all of the above

Using latest Eclipse Kepler with everything updated.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

when you run app it resolves artifact from workspace and it doesn't look into maven local repository, when you invoke maven command from eclipse (maven build) it invokes native `mvn` or embedded in both case it looks up for dependency in local maven repository and it doesn't find it

so to fix this, you run maven build on project B first with goal `mvn clean install` and then invoke your maven build on project A that will work

Comment: So the option "Resolve Workspace Artifacts" in the Maven run configuration is a functionless switch that doesn't do anything ? Why is it even there then ?

Comment: It is useful to calculate classpath referring projects inside workspace, when you invoke `mvn` it doesn't count

Comment: But that makes no sense. The ONLY thing that dialog can do is invoke Maven. So why would that option be there if it didn't 'count' while invoking Maven ?

Comment: well it is because if you add some method in other project which is dependency of main project, you won't have to clean install everytime it can resolve from workspace while you are developping it in IDE

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't actually do that. What are you basing that on ?

Comment: it does it with its internal builder, when you launch external `mvn` builder it doesn't do it

Comment: Ok, then we are back to my last comment: why would there be an option in the dialog to launch the mvn tool that doesn't actually affect the mvn tool ? That makes no sense at all. It sounds like you are confusing the project setting "Enable Workspace Resolution" with the setting I'm talking about.

Comment: because those two are separate things (mvn tool and eclipse's classpath manager)

Comment: Yes. And your position is that the mvn tool option is not supposed to affect the mvn tool run (nor anything else, as turning it off does not affect the internal builder) ?

Comment: I didn't get your last statement, could you please elaborate

Comment: There are two separate things. The internal build, that is affected by the project setting "Enable Workspace Resolution". Everything you have said so far applies to the internal build. But there is also an option in the Maven run settings, called "Resolve Workspace Artifacts". This setting does not affect the internal build, but it's also not affecting the Maven run build. So what is it affecting ? Is it broken ? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: workspace resolution effects internal build, the one which you trigger by project > build project, it doesn't affect external builder

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Again: I'm not talking about that. I'm talking about "Resolve Workspace Artifacts" in the Run As Maven run configuration, which does not affect the internal build.

Comment: to validate it, have two proejcts in your workspace A & B, A depends on B, consume any class from B in A, change method signature in B and see reflection of it in A while having enable workspace resolution, now try disable workspace resolution and see the difference

Comment: The option I am talking about does not affect it (or anything else).

Comment: can you post the screenshot of which option exactly you are talking about

Comment: I see, I was confused by `enable workspace resolution`, can you execute it with and without that option and with `-X` option and post the command info (should be there in first 10 lines) and diff it

Comment: After a bunch of debugging, the only difference I can see is that a property called m2eclipse.workspace.state is being set - how that manages to affect maven.exe is a mystery to me, but further tests with a clean workspace have shown that it indeed behaves exactly as expected - it pulls in dependencies from the workspace instead of any repository. Why it doesn't work in my case is not clear to me, but has probably to do with my relatively complex master project.

Comment: cool, glad that you resolved it, as part of how it fixes it, I think it is using maven embedded not external and somehow it has this mechanism to set it